# Make an object with sql table's datatype

Tags: java

This might be very silly question but,
I have a `hashmap<string, list<string>>` and I am putting the values in the hashmap. Now the issue is that the variables of hashmap are the variables for the sql data table. Is there any way in which I can simply use the class of the sql data table rather than creating a local class and making a constructor?

```
public class Student {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    public Long getId() { return this.id; }

    @Column(name = "studentName1")
    public String studentName1;

    @Column(name = "studentName2")
    public String studentName2;

    @Column(name = "studentName3")
    public String studentName3;
}

import java.util.*; 
  
public class ConcurrentHashMapExample { 
  
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        // Creating ConcurrentHashMap 
        Map<String, List<String>> 
            my_cmmap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>>(); 
  
        // Adding elements to the map 
        // using put() method 
        my_cmmap.put("1", Arrays.asList("2","3")); 
        my_cmmap.put("2", Arrays.asList("4","5")); 
    } 
}
```

Now, `mu_cmmap.values()` will give the `list<string>`. Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: Please include more details and clarify the problem. As it stands now, I don't know what the question really is about.

Comment: @Matt the question is if there is anyway in which we can do `Student s = my_cmmap.values()` so that I can do `s. studentName2 ` etc. Based on the current code, I cannot. Can I make a constructor of `Student`?

Comment: A direct assignment does not work because the types are different. You could add a constructor that takes a `Collection<List<String>>` or create a (static) mapper if you don't want a constructor. I still do not fully understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you edit the question and add an example of what exactly you want to do? What is the input/output and what is the desired functionality?